# Android emulator x86 HAXM GPU Windows 7 crash BSOD

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't know English but I will try to explain.

I use last version Android SDK, run from AVD Manager emulator intel x86 with intel HAXM and it work Fine, but when I Enable host GPU then windows 7 crash BSOD

This happen on Windows 7 x32 and x64. I update all drivers and update BIOS, but this not help.
Intel Virtualization Technology enabled in BIOS.
My notebook: HP ProBook 4530s, core i3-2330m, amd radeon HD 6490M, 4gb ram

May anyone know how to solve this problem?

On my desktope pc emulator x86 with HAXM and host GPU enable work fine.
I read somewhere that trouble because of notebook have 2 GPU discrete and integrated...

BSOD screen: http://postimg.org/image/805pl14jx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happen ONLY when PC out from sleep mode! Need reboot pc if it was in sleep mode!

Answer (score 2):

I've been experienced this on my machine running Windows 10 (Macbook pro bootcamp). But after a lot of googeling I've found the solution on a medium post.

The solution consists in restarting the Intel HAXM service to restore its state as it is before running any virtual machine after starting a fresh Windows session.

Open a command prompt with administrator rights and run the following:

```
tasklist | findstr "qemu" >nul || net stop "IntelHaxm" >nul && net start "IntelHaxm" >nul
```

You should now be able to start the emulator without getting any bluescreen.
You could also create a batch file that runs as a service.

Source: https://medium.com/@andrea.bresolin/windows-10-on-mac-with-boot-camp-making-intel-haxm-work-without-crashing-the-system-39555854f815

Comment: This is especially important on Mac because in some Bootcamp & Windows configuration, Virtualization can only be enabled by booting to OSX first and then rebooting to Windows. So using sleep mode is far more practical than having to boot twice every time.

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS for Intel virtualization technology and enable it if it's available. Then install necessary drivers from sdk manager.

Comment: I was facing this problem before, now its working after enabling Intel® Virtualization Technology.

Comment: Intel virtualization technology enabled