# BSOD on android emulator startup (android studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I get the error message below when firing up the android emulator from android studio. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Googling "intelhaxm.sys BSOD" gives some search results and at least one on StackOverflow: [Android emulator x86 HAXM GPU Windows 7 crash BSOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763287/android-emulator-x86-haxm-gpu-windows-7-crash-bsod). I haven't had this problem myself, so can't say if any of the ideas there help.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I didn't see that before I posted. I tried running the command even though my computer never went to sleep. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug affecting all Core 2 series processors that are meant to be supported by Intel HAXM. That is those which have VT-x but not EPT. After posting it on the Github, I was told to roll back to version 7.2.0 and after some more issues I was able to get the emulator running. In the end the performance was terrible so I went to Genymotion which has a free edition for personal use.